# What is the difference between keyof inside and outside of indexer?

Tags: typescript, generics, type-alias

Suppose we have the following TypeScript code:

```
type ForwardVal<T> = { 
    [K in keyof T]: string; 
};
type ForwardKeyOf<T extends string | number | symbol> = { 
    [K in T]: string; 
};

type ByObj   = ForwardVal<number[]>;         // string[]
type ByKeyOf = ForwardKeyOf<keyof number[]>; // { length: string, toString: string, ... }

type foo =   ByObj['push'];   // (...items: string[]) => number
type bar = ByKeyOf['push'];   // string
```

Why is not `foo` a string, but `bar` is? What is the difference between forwarding a `keyof obj` and having `Key in T` from forwarding `obj` itself and doing `Key in keyof T` inside of a mapped type?
Isn't `T` parameter just replaced by its given value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, there is no difference, `keyof` is just a union type of all the keys (property and method names) that exist in the `keyof` argument.

But starting with TypeScript 3.1, there is one special case - the same syntax with `keyof` is used to create [mapped types over tuples and arrays](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html).

> In TypeScript 3.1, mapped object types over tuples and arrays now
>   produce new tuples/arrays, rather than creating a new type where
>   members like push(), pop(), and length are converted.

So, when there is a uniform (homomorphic) mapped type

```
type ForwardVal<T> = { 
    [K in keyof T]: string; 
};
```

and it's argument `T` is a tuple or array type (in your case it's `ForwardVal<number[]>`), then as documentation says, "only numeric properties are converted", producing `string[]` as resulting type.

Comment: Thank you, it was just a coincidence to test my type mapper over an array, now I need to to ckeck the latest language updates)